# How to set a minimum scale for Cloud Run on GKE services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run, knative-serving

I'm using Cloud Run on Google Kubernetes Engine and I'm able to deploy and access services without a problem.

But since I'm running on GKE and paying for the cluster 24/7 it makes no sense to scale a deployment to zero and always have a cold start for the first request.

I've found that's it's possible to set `minScale` for the Knative autoscaler to disable scale to zero [here](https://knative.dev/v0.4-docs/serving/samples/autoscale-go/), [here](https://github.com/knative/serving/tree/master/docs/scaling) and [here](https://github.com/knative/serving/issues/2669), but I have no idea where to put it.

There are a lot of configurations, services and workloads inside GKE for Isito and Knative-Serving, but I couldn't find anything matching.

Which file or configuration do I have to edit to set `minScale` to `1`? Or won't this be possible since Cloud Run manages the specific template internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `kubectl`, you should be able to set the annotation `autoscaling.knative.dev/minScale: "1"` on your Knative service.

See [this page](https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/6086685fd736d2ddcbe1f3d0d9f3ca5ff62504ee/docs/scaling/README.md) for more info

Comment: There is no Knative service, so I don't know here to set the annotation. That's what my question is about, sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: What do you mean 'there is no Knative service'? When you deploy to Cloud Run on GKE, you create a Knative Service object.

Comment: Sorry, I might have misunterstood you. Can you explain what you mean by 'Knative Service object'?

Comment: When you deploy to Cloud Run on GKE, you can use `kubectl` to inspect the created services:  `kubectl list ksvc`. Using `kubectl apply`, you can set this annotation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was somehow looking for a generic Knative service for setting the `minScale` and not for individual services. I've now set `minScale` on each service and everything is working as expected.